# VBScript copy Column to the last row

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I have a spreadsheet that has 1 header that I'm trying to copy the data from excluding the header to another worksheet that is in another workbook that has 2 headers in it. I found this snippet of code online, but it's giving me an error stating that there is an expected ')' on Line 25.

```
  copyLastrow = ws1.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

Around Here:

```
 searchorder:=xlByRows
```

Here is the Script:

```
Const FILE1 = "C:\Users\roperalta\Desktop\Book1.xlsx"
Const FILE2 = "C:\Users\roperalta\Desktop\PBJ_Excel_to_XML_Template_v_2_00_3.xlsx"

Dim LastRow
Dim xlApp 
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim wb1, wb2
With xlApp
    .Visible = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    Set wb1 = .Workbooks.Open(FILE1, 0, False)
    Set wb2 = .Workbooks.Open(FILE2, 0, False)
End With

Dim ws1, ws2
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet0 (2)")
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Header")

ws2.Range("B3:D3").Value2 = ws1.Range("B2:D2").Value2

Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet0")
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Employees")

copyLastrow = ws1.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

pasteLastrowG = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
'pasteLastrowH ...
'pasteLastrowI ...

ws1.Range("J" & copyLastrow).Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("A" & pasteLastrowG)
'Copy and paste B code here
'Copy and paste C code here

wb2.Save
wb1.Close
'wb2.Close
'xlApp.Quit

Set ws1 = Nothing
Set ws2 = Nothing
Set wb1 = Nothing
'Set wb2 = Nothing
'Set xlApp = Nothing
```

Comment: I don't know VBScript very well, but maybe it doesn't permit named parameters?  But you will have to also ensure that you set values for `xlByRows`, `xlPrevious`, etc, because those constants are normally provided to VBA code by the Excel library but you are using VBScript and therefore won't have the library to define those constants.

Comment: And things like `Rows.Count` will need to be changed to be `ws2.Rows.Count` because the unqualified `Rows` object won't be defaulted to `Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows` by VBA because you aren't using VBA.

Comment: Hmm, yeah it might be because it's a script, I found this from a macro... I wonder if there is a work around for this?

Comment: @YowE3K you are correct.  No Name Parameters.

Comment: The workaround is to pass the parameters (without the "name:=" part) in the order in which the method expects them.

Comment: @ThomasInzina Does VBScript allow "missing" parameters?  I.e. will `copyLastrow = ws1.Cells.Find("*", , , , 1, 2).Row` work?

Comment: @YowE3K yes it does.

Comment: Thanks that did it, but now i'm getting an error for the line below this one at pasteLastrow, Could it be because I'm using .End(xlUp) which is part of the VBA library? Could i use a constant value for this as well?

Comment: `xlUp` (and all other constants) will need to be set specifically, so `xlByRows` has a value of `1` and `xlPrevious` has a value of `2` which is why I used those in my suggested `.Find("*", , , , 1, 2)`.  `xlUp` is `-4162`.

Answer (score 0):

VBScript doesn't allow Name Parameters and does not know about the Excel.Application NameSpace. For this reason you will need to fully qualify all references to Excel.Application object, which you should always do anyway.  Likewise, you'll should declare Const variables to replace the Excel.Application enumerations and constants.

```
Const FILE1 = "C:\Users\roperalta\Desktop\Book1.xlsx"
Const FILE2 = "C:\Users\roperalta\Desktop\PBJ_Excel_to_XML_Template_v_2_00_3.xlsx"
Const xlPrevious = 2
Const xlByRows = 1
Dim LastRow
Dim xlApp, wb1, wb2, ws1, ws2
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

With xlApp
    .Visible = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    Set wb1 = .Workbooks.Open(FILE1, 0, False)
    Set wb2 = .Workbooks.Open(FILE2, 0, False)
End With

Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet0 (2)")
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Header")

ws2.Range("B3:D3").Value2 = ws1.Range("B2:D2").Value2

Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet0")
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Employees")

copyLastrow = ws1.Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

pasteLastrowG = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
'pasteLastrowH ...
'pasteLastrowI ...

ws1.Range("J" & copyLastrow).Copy ws2.Range("A" & pasteLastrowG)
'Copy and paste B code here
'Copy and paste C code here

wb2.Close True
wb1.Close False
xlApp.Quit
```

Comment: Is the xlUp an excel enumeration or constant, I Don't know how this value is used. Getting a run time error at the beginning of this line: pasteLastrowG

Comment: `xlUp` needs to be set as `-4162`

Comment: So there are no errors anymore, but the results show no output.